# Realm Shuffle RLMArray

Tags: ios, swift, realm

How would I go about taking an RLMArray and shuffling it so that the current items in the RLMArray are randomized.

I have looked through the documentation for the RLMArray, however I haven't seen a good way to shuffle it.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet will probably be to create an `NSArray` from the `RLMArray`, shuffle the `NSArray` (Fisher-Yates is a great algorithm for that), remove all objects from the `RLMArray`, and add them back in order.